# Return two random rows without duplicate properties in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a table of customer addresses:

```
Name           |   AddressLine
-------------------------------
John Smith      | 123 Nowheresville
Jane Doe        | 456 Evergreen Terrace
John Smith      | 999 Somewhereelse
Joe Bloggs      | 1 Second Ave
```

I would like to return two random rows from this table, but I do not want to return two rows with the same Name (example of what I don't want):

```
Name           |   AddressLine
-------------------------------
John Smith      | 123 Nowheresville
John Smith      | 999 Somewhereelse
```

How can I do this in Postgres?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select distinct on (name) t.*
from t
order by name, random();
```

Comment: Will that ever return the second row for John Smith? `999 Somewhereelse`?

Comment: @LukeSchlangen . . . It could.  `random()` is random.